# Is it possible to use Postgresql's file_fdw foreign data wrapper to read a file on a network share?

Tags: postgresql

Here's my use case:

I have a machine running Postgresql which was set up for performance. But its storage capacity may be limited. I need to ingest quite a lot of data to this machine. Such data is stored in another machine within our LAN, so I like to use Postgresql's `COPY` command to read that data into the server, using `file_fdw` to create a foreign table with the source file.

However, [the docs say the filename "Must be an absolute path name"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html).

I tried anyway doing something like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw; 
CREATE SERVER csv_src FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw; 
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE "mytable" (
  "a1" INTEGER,
  "a2" INTEGER
)
SERVER csv_src 
OPTIONS ( 
FILENAME '\\OTHER_MACHINE/myfile.csv', 
    FORMAT 'csv', 
    DELIMITER '|', 
    HEADER 'true', 
    NULL 'NULL', 
    ENCODING 'UTF-8'
);
```

But I get `Kernel error: ERROR:  could not open file "\\OTHER_MACHINE/myfile.csv" for reading: Invalid argument`

So I guess it is because, in principle, `file-fdw` cannot handle files on network shares, but only local files with an absolute path.

My question is, if that is actually the case and if someone know of a workaround.

My current workaround is to compress the files in the other machine and use `file-fdw`'s `program` option to unzip and read the contents from stdout, instead of the normal `file-fdw`'s filename. This works because the unzip program can in fact open and read the file in the network share (`\\OTHER_MACHINE/myfile.zip`), but I just feel (or want) that it should just work like that with normal plain files.

Well, other workaround that should work is to simply copy the files to the Postgresql machine. That is however quite inefficient and not feasible in my case, due to the storage limitations.

Comment: What are these backslashes supposed to mean?

Comment: Are you on windows?  Try forward slashes, not backslashes.  Or a drive letter.

Comment: yeah, sorry I forgot to say. Poastgresql is running on a Windows machine. And the backslashes are how you usually access a network share on windows. I've tried the forward slashes already and it does not work